# Hide column from Query

Tags: oracle

I don't want rank column but still, want the data in the same format by applying dense rank.

```
select ename,position,deptno,dense_rank() over(partition by deptno order by ename asc) as rank from emp  where deptno in ('10','30');
```

[image]

Comment: That query will always return 1 for rank. Should you be ordering by employee?

Comment: @RossBush..No, I'm not. However, I have tried and it gives me rank like 1,2,3 for dept 10 and 1,2,3,4,5,6 for dept no 30

Comment: Can you post sample data.

Comment: You are ordering by the partition. In dense_rank the records are going to be given a sequential value by your order (inside the partition). How can this not be anything but 1?

Comment: @RossBush...Please check the sample data in the question.

Comment: The edit made by @xQBert will return what (I think) you were looking for. Why not simply omit that field from the result set. The dense_rank function does not affect the number of rows returned.

Comment: @RossBush...Yeah, I can do in that way however, I want to give a try with analytical function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need the rank just order by deptno first then ename.

```
SELECT ename,position,deptno,
FROM emp 
WHERE deptno in ('10','30')
ORDER BY DeptNo, Ename
```

Using the analytical function two options derived table or CTE

Derived table/inline view.

```
SELECT ename,position,deptno 
FROM (select ename,position,deptno,dense_rank() over(partition by deptno order by ename asc) as rank 
      from emp  
      where deptno in ('10','30')) Z
ORDER BY deptNo, rank
```

Common Table  Expression (CTE):

```
with Z AS (SELECT ename,position,deptno
                , dense_rank() over(partition by deptno order by ename asc) as rank 
          FROM emp  
          WHERE deptno in ('10','30'))
SELECT ename,position,deptno  
FROM z 
ORDER BY deptno, rank
```

Both these last 2 techniques simply avoid exposing the rank function to the outer query in which the results are returned.   They are "Tricks" and sub-optimal execution time.  unless there's a specific reason to have the rank data; I'd not use it.

Comment: I was trying with the analytical function.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh I get that; but the overhead of the window function doesn't seem worth it.  I've added two ways you could do it; but I don't see the reason to if you're not exposing the rank to the query.